# SQLAlchemy bulk insert auto-incremment

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, auto-increment

Edit 2 :

```
class MethodCall(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'methodCall'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String( 255 ), unique = True)
    actions = relationship("Action")

def test_bulk_insert():
    ses = DBSession()
    mc = MethodCall()
    a1 = Action()
    a2 = Action()
    a1.lfn = getFile(ses, 'toto')
    a2.lfn = getFile(ses, 'toto')
    mc.actions.append(a1)
    mc.actions.append(a2)
```

Edit :
Now i have two tables with a relationship :

```
class Action(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'action'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    file_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('file.id'))
    lfn = relationship("File")
    methodCall_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('methodCall.id'))

class File(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'file'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String( 255 ), unique = True)
```

When I insert two actions like this :

```
a1 = Action()
a2 = Action()
a1.lfn = getFile(ses, 'toto')
a2.lfn = getFile(ses, 'toto')
ses.bulk_save_objects([a1,a2])

def getFile(session,n):
    instance = session.query( File ).filter_by( name = n ).first()
    if not instance:
        instance = File( name=n )
        session.add( instance )
        session.commit()
    return instance
```

The file_id in table action is not set, it is null.
How can I do ?

> I have a little problem with SQLALchemy when inserting row.
>
> I have a table file :
>
> `class File(Base):
>       __tablename__ = 'file'
>       id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)`
>
> when I insert two files like this :
>
> ```
> f1 = File( id = 1 )
> f2 = File( id =2 )
> session.add(f1)
> session.add(f2)
> session.commit()
> ```
>
> It's a bulk insert :
>
> ```
> 2015-06-16 11:27:57,057 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
> 2015-06-16 11:27:57,058 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO file (id) VALUES (%s)
> 2015-06-16 11:27:57,058 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ((1,), (2,))
> 2015-06-16 11:27:57,060 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
> ```
>
> but when I don't precise id, the insertion is one by one:
>
> ```
> f1 = File(  )
> f2 = File( )
> session.add(f1)
> session.add(f2)
> session.commit()
>
> 2015-06-16 11:28:46,648 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO file () VALUES ()
> 2015-06-16 11:28:46,649 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
> 2015-06-16 11:28:46,654 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO file () VALUES ()
> 2015-06-16 11:28:46,654 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
> 2015-06-16 11:28:46,655 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
> ```
>
> Is there any way when I don't precise id to insert in bulk with
>   auto-increment?
>
> Thank you

Comment: What's wrong? The id field is assigned by DB in this case, not by SQLAlchemy

Comment: In this case it's not a bulk insertion, and i want a bulk insertion

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=bulk_save_objects#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects might help

Comment: thank you but if i have an other table with a foreign key, it doesn't work, the foreign key is null

Comment: Please include your full example in question.

Comment: Hmm, looks like bulk operations bypass relationship logic. However, for your current example solution is present. Instead of `a1.lfn = getFile(ses, 'toto')` use `a1.file_id = getFile(ses, 'toto').id`. So instead of using relationships you will directly use foreign key value.

Comment: Thank you, but if now i have the methodCall table, is it possible to keep relationship ?

Comment: No, all bulk operations bypass relationship logic, you'll have to manually work with foreign keys. In your example you'll first need to insert `MethodCall` record, then assign its `id` to `methodCall_id` field of `Action` objects.